# SwiftUI push vstack to remaining length of screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I currently have a product page view that I am having some issues with. My goal here is to push the taupe color to the bottom of the screen. I've tried using Spacer(), and adding a VStack under the VStack with Spacer() in it but it is not pushing to the bottom of the screen. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
ZStack {
            Color.white
           ScrollView  {
                VStack {
                    KFImage(URL(string: bottle?.image ?? "Test"))
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
                        .padding([.top], 50)
                }
                .padding([.bottom], 40)
            
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(bottle?.name ?? "Test")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        Spacer()
                        SpiritTag(spirit: bottle?.varietal ?? "Other")
                    }
                    if((bottle?.brand_id) != nil) {
                        NavigationLink(destination: BrandView(brandId: bottle?.brand_id ?? "1")) {
                            HStack {
                                KFImage(URL(string: brand?.logo ?? "Test"))
                                 .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    Text("\(brand?.name ?? "Unknown")")
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    Text("\(brand?.bottle_count ?? 0) bottles")
                                        .font(.caption)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                          self.show_modal = true
                        }) {
                            Text("Add to list")
                        }
                        .frame(height: 15)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color("Onyx"))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .sheet(isPresented: self.$show_modal) {
                            CollectionAddition(userId: session.auth.currentUser!.uid, bottleId: bottle!.id)
                        }
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Information")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold).padding([.bottom], 1)
                        Text(bottle?.information ?? "")
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    }.padding([.bottom])
                }
                .padding()
                .padding(.top)
                .background(Color("Tope"))
                .cornerRadius(30, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
                .offset(x: 0, y: -30.0)
           }
           .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
```

Comment: Try adding `.frame(height: .infinity)` to your `VStack()`. That should cause it to expand and use all of the space. You should also provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You're using a `ScrollView` that wraps everything. That's sort of antithetical to the idea of pushing one part toward the bottom of the screen. If it's at the bottom, under what circumstances would it scroll?